# elasticsearch and angular js Interworking error

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

Hi i wondering that ploblem so i want ask somebody
so please give me solution?

I make html file like that photo
but when i open this html file this file not working…
any data not diplay

what is the ploblem in this html file?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgsmk.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="QueryController">
</div>

<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/elasticsearch-browser/elasticsearch.angular.js"></script>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['elasticsearch']);

    // Create the es service from the esFactory
    myApp.service('es', function (esFactory) {
        return esFactory({ host: 'localhost:9200'});
    });

    myApp.controller('ServerHealthController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {

        es.cluster.health(function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                $scope.data = err.message;

            } else {
                $scope.data = resp;

            }
        });
    });

    // We define an Angular controller that returns query results,
    // Inputs: $scope and the 'es' service

    myApp.controller('QueryController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {

// search for documents
        es.search({
            index: 'epowersyst',
            type: 'logs',
            body: {
              query:
                {
                  match_all : {} }
                }

        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.hits = response;
            console.log($scope.hits)
            alert("hits값 : " + response);
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, please read [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask pages to learn how to ask a good question to get a good answer. Posting an image of your code is a problem because someone has to manually type it all to test it.

Comment: I have edited the question again. thank you!